# Find number of real values of $x$ satisfying $2\log_3(x-2)+\log_3(x-4)^2=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Find number of real values of $x$ satisfying $2\log_3(x-2)+\log_3(x-4)^2=0$

**My approach:-**

$2\log_3(x-2)+\log_3(x-4)^2=0$

$2\log_3(x-2)+2\log_3(x-4)=0$

$2(\log_3(x-2)+\log_3(x-4))=0$

$2(\log_3(x-2)(x-4))=0$

$(x-2)(x-4)=1$

$x^2-6x+7=0$

$x=3+\sqrt2$

$x=3-\sqrt2$   (Rejected as doesn't satisfy the domain of the equation provided in the problem)

Therefore, $1$ real value of $x$, but the answer is given as $2$. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: As $(x-2)>0$, so there will be only one real rooy. you are right.

Comment: You make a mistake writing $\log[(x-4)^2]=2\log(x-4)$. There is another root

Comment: As mentioned before, write $[(x-2)(x-4)]^2=1$ or $(x-2)(x-4)=\pm 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $b, x > 0$, with $b \neq 1$, then we can apply the power rule
$$\log_b x^n = n\log_b x$$
You have to be careful about applying this rule when $n$ is even since $x^n$ may be positive even when $x$ is negative.

**Domain:**

Since $x - 2 > 0 \implies x > 2$, the term $2\log_3 (x - 2)$ is defined when $x > 2$.

Notice that $(x - 4)^2 > 0$ unless $x = 4$.  Therefore, the term $\log_3 (x - 4)^2$ is defined for each real number $x$ such that $x \neq 4$.

Since both of these conditions must hold, the domain of the expression
$$2\log_3 (x - 2) + \log_3 (x - 4)^2$$
is $(2, 4) \cup (4, \infty)$ since we require that $x > 2$ and $x \neq 4$.

**Where did you make your error?**

You incorrectly simplified the term $\log_3 (x - 4)^2$ when $2 < x < 4$.

If $x > 4$, then $x - 4 > 0$, so we can apply the power rule to obtain
$$\log_3 (x - 4)^2 = 2\log_3 (x - 4)$$
However, if $2 < x < 4$, then $x - 4 < 0$, so $\log_3 (x - 4)$ is undefined.  On the other hand, $-x + 4 = -(x - 4) > 0$.  Thus, if $2 < x < 4$, then
$$\log_3 (x - 4)^2 = 2\log_3 (-x + 4)$$
Notice that
$$|x - 4| = \begin{cases}
            x - 4 & \text{if $x \geq 4$}\\
            -x + 4 & \text{if $x < 4$}
            \end{cases}
$$
Thus,
$$\log_3 (x - 4)^2 = 2\log_3 |x - 4|$$

In general, if $b > 0$, with $b \neq 1$, $x \neq 0$, and $n$ is an even integer,
$$\log_b x^n = n\log_b |x|$$

With that in mind, let's proceed.

**Solution:**

*Case 1*:  If $x > 4$, then $|x - 4| = x - 4$, so we obtain
\begin{align*}
2\log_3 (x - 2) + \log_3 (x - 4)^2 & = 0\\
2\log_3 (x - 2) + 2\log_3 |x - 4| & = 0\\
\log_3 (x - 2) + \log_3 |x - 4| & = 0\\
\log_3 (x - 2) + \log_3 (x - 4) & = 0\\
\log_3 (x - 2)(x - 4) & = 0\\
\log_3 (x^2 - 6x + 8) & = 0\\
x^2 - 6x + 8 & = 3^0\\
x^2 - 6x + 8 & = 1\\
x^2 - 6x  & = -7\\
x^2 - 6x + 9 & = 2\\
(x - 3)^2 & = 2\\
|x - 3| & = \sqrt{2}\\
x - 3 & = \pm \sqrt{2}\\
x & = 3 \pm \sqrt{2}
\end{align*}
Since $3 - \sqrt{2} < 4$, we reject that solution.  Hence, $x = 3 + \sqrt{2}$ is the only solution for this case.

*Case 2*:  If $2 < x < 4$, then $|x - 4| = -x + 4 = 4 - x$, so we obtain
\begin{align*}
2\log_3 (x - 2) + \log_3 (x - 4)^2 & = 0\\
2\log_3 (x - 2) + 2\log_3 |x - 4| & = 0\\
\log_3 (x - 2) + \log_3 |x - 4| & = 0\\
\log_3 (x - 2) + \log_3 (-x + 4) & = 0\\
\log_3 (x - 2)(-x + 4) & = 0\\
\log_3 (-x^2 + 6x - 8) & = 0\\
-x^2 + 6x - 8 & = 3^0\\
-x^2 + 6x - 8 & = 1\\
-x^2 + 6x - 9 & = 0\\
x^2 - 6x + 9 & = 0\\
(x - 3)^2 & = 0\\
x - 3 & = 0\\
x & = 3
\end{align*}
Since $3$ satisfies $2 < x < 4$, it is a valid solution.

Thus, the solution set is $S = \{3, 3 + \sqrt{2}\}$, so there are two solutions.

Comment: While applying power rule in case for any even power of an expression, do I need to always use the absolute value of the expression ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  I have edited my answer accordingly.